# UITableView cell misbehaving, showing no disclosure and more

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I have a really strange issue where my UITableView content has started to misbehave greatly.

1. There are no lines in between cells regardless what I set the line Separator property to.
2. The disclosure caret doesn't show, even though it shows in the Storyboard editor.
3. Setting the table view in edit mode doesn't show any edit widgets. The cell content is actually totally un-effected (it should animate to make room for the delete icon, right?).
4. But when going from edit mode to "normal" mode suddenly the cell is shifted to the right (without animations). It's the cell, not the contents, that is shifted to the right. I know because I've tried it with grouped style.

Anyone seen this? Anyone have a hint to throw me? This stupid thing is in the way for my apps progress!

Please let me know if I can add any information to make my question clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. I had forgot to call `[super layoutSubViews]` in my custom cell class. Gah!